# shell script for executing a command which accepts command line arguments and store output to a variable

Tags: shell, jq

When i execute below command, it is printing the required thing i.e abcd1g2f

```
cat priv.json | jq '.data | map(select(.properties | any(.[]; .value == "client_release")) |.id)[0]'
```

but when i execute same from shell script (this is requirement), it is printing null. can someone please help me?

below is the shell script (test.sh) i wrote:

```
get_priv0=$(cat priv.json | jq '.data | map(select(.properties | any(.[]; .value == "$1")) |.id)[0]')
echo $get_priv0
```

command which i executed

```
./test.sh client_release
```

JSON file (priv.json) is below:

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": "abcd1g2f",
    "resourceURI": "https://somerepo.com/service/local/privileges/abcd1g2f",
    "name": "release1",
    "description": "release1",
    "type": "target",
    "userManaged": true,
    "properties": [{
        "key": "repositoryGroupId",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "key": "method",
        "value": "create,read"
    }, {
        "key": "repositoryId",
        "value": "client_release"
    }, {
        "key": "repositoryTargetId",
        "value": "1"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "asdf1k4g",
    "resourceURI": "https://somerepo.com/service/local/privileges/asdf1k4g",
    "name": "release2",
    "description": "release2",
    "type": "target",
    "userManaged": true,
    "properties": [{
        "key": "repositoryGroupId",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "key": "method",
        "value": "read"
    }, {
        "key": "repositoryId",
        "value": "formal_release"
    }, {
        "key": "repositoryTargetId",
        "value": "1"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "hirk5d7b3l",
    "resourceURI": "https://somerepo.com/service/local/privileges/hirk5d7b3l",
    "name": "release3",
    "description": "release3",
    "type": "target",
    "userManaged": true,
    "properties": [{
        "key": "repositoryGroupId",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "key": "method",
        "value": "create,read"
    }, {
        "key": "repositoryId",
        "value": "client_release"
    }, {
        "key": "repositoryTargetId",
        "value": "1"
    }]
}]
}
```

Comment: The problem is usage of `$1` within single quotes.

Comment: `get_priv0=$(jq --arg value "$value" '.data | map(select(.properties | any(.[]; .value == $value)) |.id)[0]' <json.priv)` -- note the use of `--arg` to create a `jq` variable from your shell variable.